# Highlight a sub-sequence on matplotlib plot with specific x-value range

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am using `matplotlib` to plot a Time-series data on Jupyter Notebook. My Time-series data is a `numpy.array`. 
Here is my plot : 
[image]

How can I highlight a specific sub-sequence on that plot ? 
Here is my example :

[image]

Comment: Try re-plotting that sub-range with a very thick line width (e.g. `plot(x,y,lw=10, c='yellow', zorder=-1)` and see if that is enough for your needs. The keyword `zorder` determines in which order different elements are drawn -- smaller values are drawn before larger values.

Comment: @ThomasKühn I tried but that not what I looking for. But do you completely understand the question ? I can explain more detail if you want.

Comment: @TrungTínTrần, did you try Thomas's solution? It should do exactly that what you were asking ...

Comment: @ThomasKühn, what about posting your comment as answer? ;-) I think it perfectly answers this question...

Comment: @MaxU ok, let's me try that again. Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: @MaxU I won't have time before the evening -- would you have time to write up an answer? Alternatively, chances are high that this is a duplicate ...

Comment: @ThomasKühn, posted it as an answer (totally based on your comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a small demo based on [@Thomas Kühn comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238471/highlight-a-sub-sequence-on-matplotlib-plot-with-specific-x-value-range#comment83459364_48238471):

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.plot(x[60:80], np.sin(x[60:80]), lw=10, c='yellow', zorder=-1)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks MaxU and Thomas. Now it's work !! I am just misunderstood the keyword `x` and `y`.

Comment: Perfect answer! You got my upvote already, just didn't have time to comment ;)

Comment: @ThomasKühn, thank you! I didn’t know the trick with the “zorder”, so I have learned something new from your comment! :)